# Sencha Touch with PhoneGap - how to determine IP address when on WI-FI

Tags: networking, cordova, ip, wifi, sencha-touch-2

I'm using `Sencha Touch 2` with `PhoneGap`. I need to determine my device IP address when connected to a Wi-Fi network. Is there any way to do it? Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to create a plugin to read the IP address of the device. Here is a tutorial I wrote that covers how to write an Android plugin for Cordova 2.0.0 and the example is getting an IP address.

http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.com/2012/08/so-you-wanna-write-phonegap-200-android.html